# Transfer the property sale proceed to Lebanon

Tags: transfer

I'm a US citizen. I currently live in Lebanon. I sold my house in Rochester NY and want to transfer the proceeds of the sale to Lebanon by a bank wire transfer. In case I show the bank the origin of the funds (certificate of the sale), can the bank refuse to make such transfer?  If yes, what should I do?